# Pipenv gets blocked while running with Docker in Gitlab

Tags: python, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipenv

I created this simple project in Gitlab:

https://gitlab.com/PequeX/deleteme

With a [Pipfile that installs only a couple of packages](https://gitlab.com/PequeX/deleteme/blob/master/Pipfile):

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]
pytest = "*"

[packages]
requests = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

And a very simple [`.gitlab-ci.yml` file](https://gitlab.com/PequeX/deleteme/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml):

```
image: peque/python-devel

before_script:
  - pipenv sync --dev

python36:
  script:
    - pipenv run pytest
```

There is also the [autogenerated Pipfile.lock file](https://gitlab.com/PequeX/deleteme/blob/master/Pipfile.lock). Which I will not paste here as it is not very interesting.

Now, the problem is Gitlab seems to get blocked when calling `pipenv sync`:

https://gitlab.com/PequeX/deleteme/-/jobs/171273142

There is no output printed on the log and no error. It just gets blocked forever. And then, eventually, it timeouts (because Gitlab would not let you run a pipeline forever).

What is wrong or how could I successfully run `pipenv sync`? Note that I would like to keep using the same [`peque/python-devel` image](https://github.com/Peque/docker-python-devel) from Docker Hub, as I need to have multiple Python versions installed for my pipelines.

### Update

Tried unsetting the `CI` variable as @Hernan Garcia suggests in his answer, with no luck:

- [Branch](https://gitlab.com/PequeX/deleteme/tree/hernan)
- [Error](https://gitlab.com/PequeX/deleteme/-/jobs/171370179) (does not find package)

I also tried with `pipenv shell` as @Hernan Garcia suggests in his comments, with no luck:

- [Branch](https://gitlab.com/PequeX/deleteme/tree/cishell)
- [Error](https://gitlab.com/PequeX/deleteme/-/jobs/172044675) (`pipenv shell` crashes)

Comment: Can you add `--verbose`? 
https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#pipenv-sync

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in another answer defining an empty `CI` variable will solve the build stuck issue.

Then the second issue that you will face due to not finding `pytest` and this is because the docker image is missing `which` package and this makes `pipenv` not able to find pytest.

The final gitlab-ci.yml file should be similar to the following:

```
image: peque/python-devel

variables:
  CI: ""

before_script:
  - pipenv sync --dev
  - yum install -y which

python36:
  script:
    - pipenv run pytest
```

And the final output will be:

```
$ pipenv run pytest
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.2, pytest-4.3.0, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.9.0
rootdir: /builds/mostafahussein/deleteme, inifile:
collected 0 items

========================= no tests ran in 0.01 seconds =========================
```

---

Regarding this issue:

```
termios.error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')
```

This is because `pipenv shell` needs a `tty` to run without raising the above error however GitLab CI does not provide a tty since there are no user inputs as far as i know. So it will be better to use the first method which is `pipenv run`.

Comment: Does fix the issue, thanks. Still have to figure out what is the difference between this (perhaps too) reduced example and the real repository, which is now (after installing `which`) failing with a "core dumped" error as soon as I run the `pipenv` command. :'(

Comment: @Peque I have pulled the current docker image and everything works as expected no need to install which because i found it exist already as i can see you have pushed a new image `b7c96e8d2b98`. What is your current issue as I cannot reproduce the "core dumped" error

Comment: Yeah, I updated the image with the missing `which`, thanks. I need to work a bit on trying to produce a reduced example that would reproduce the "core dumped". I will accept your answer for now, as it currently fixes all reproducible issues.

Comment: @Peque please don't forget to add the bounty as it should be added manually and up-vote the answer.

Comment: I already upvoted the answer. I am still thinking whether or not to award the bounty. If I do not award it, it will be split between you and @hernangarcia, who also helped with the `CI` variable problem. ^^

Answer (score 1):

I could fix it by using this workaround:
https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/3534#issuecomment-464510351

Add the following to your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to unset `CI` variable:

```
variables:
    CI: ""
```

Check this succeeded job:
https://gitlab.com/hernandanielg/deleteme/-/jobs/171342796

;)

Comment: I will try that workaround, thanks! I swear I searched for `pipenv` issues, but I think I searched for the word "block", not "stuck" and that issue did not come up... :-/

Comment: I updated the repository a bit [by actually trying to use some installed package](https://gitlab.com/PequeX/deleteme/tree/hernan). Now it does not get stuck, but it says it cannot find the (supposedly correctly) installed package. Any ideas?

Comment: if I do `pipenv shell` and then `pytest` it works... to use `pipenv run pytest` seems an issue with pip

Comment: An issue with `pip` and not `pipenv` in that case? Should it be reported? I always thought `pipenv shell + xxx` was equivalent to `pipenv run xxx`.

Comment: I don't know for sure but I tried on the container image you're using and it was failing too so it's not related to gitlab-ci at all

Comment: [I tried running `pipenv shell`](https://gitlab.com/PequeX/deleteme/tree/cishell), but [it crashes too](https://gitlab.com/PequeX/deleteme/-/jobs/172044675). :-/

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the file permission. make it as readable and writable
use `chmod 777` command. 
which will give the file full permissions to read and write

Comment: Which file you mean?

Comment: whole docker file change the mode

Comment: You mean the `Dockerfile`? That is only used to generate the image that is already in Docker Hub, how could that be related to the problem in Gitlab?

Comment: the basic problem with docker file is it does not have the full permission to execute the job.  when i was working on aws batch i have faced this issue so file which is inside docker file, as well as whole docker image, give the full read-write access. i.e Chmod 777

Comment: before execting on gitlab give full access to docker image

Comment: Gitlab has access to the Docker image. It downloads and runs it without any issues. The issue is with Pipenv. I still do not know which file you mean by "file which is inside docker file".

Comment: Please change the file permission to chmod 777. before creating the docker file change the file permission of all the files. this issue occurs due to insufficient file permission.